# jQuery2.xでonメソッドをコールしたオブジェクトのセレクタをコールバック関数から参照するには？

Tags: jquery

```
$('.hogehoge .hugahuga .piyopiyo div').on('click',function(){
  index = $('.hogehoge .hugahuga .piyopiyo div').index(this)
});
```

のように、長ったらしいセレクタを2度記述するのを回避する方法は

```
target = $('.hogehoge .hugahuga .piyopiyo div')
target.on('click',function(){
  index = target.index(this)
});
```

のように変数を定義するしかないですか？

```
$('.hogehoge .hugahuga .piyopiyo div').on('click',function(e){
  index = $(e.xxx).index(this)
});
```

のようにコールバック関数の内部から呼び出すことは不可能ですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

はじめに、`$(this)` を使う方法を思いつきました。しかしこれはクリックした要素しか返ってこないため、意図した挙動をしませんでした。

```html
<div class="hogehoge">
  <div class="hugahuga">
    <div class="piyopiyo">
      <div>first</div>
      <div>second</div>
      <div>third</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

上記のような `.hogehoge .hugahuga .piyopiyo div` で引っかかる要素が同じ親要素のもとにあるならば

```js
$('.hogehoge .hugahuga .piyopiyo div').on('click',function(e){
    index = $(this).parent().find(this).index()
});
```

で動作することを確認しましたが、どうでしょうか。

Comment: @mrgrotesque 意図した挙動をするであろうコードを追加し編集しました

Comment: もう少しスマートな方法があれば…とも思うのですが、こちらの方法よりスマートな記法が自分では思いつきませんでした。ご丁寧な対応ありがとうございます。